# posts_per_page not working

Tags: wp-query, functions

For whatever reason the `posts_per_page` parameter isn't working. I already called it earlier in the template and I used `wp_reset_query()`, yet it's not working with the second instance. Any idea why?

```
 <div class="new_home_single">
<ul>
  <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6' ); ?>

  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <div class="posting_classs">
<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
    <?php 
   /*****     Thumbnail     ******/
   the_post_thumbnail(
    array(280, 150), 
    array(

    'class' => 'thumbnail_class',  //custom class for post thumbnail if any 
        'alt' => 'post thumbnail', //post thumbnail alternate title
    'title' => 'my custom title'   //Title of thumbnail
    )
   );?></a>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post_box' ); ?>>


    <h2 class="title_home"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
     <?php echo ShortenText(get_the_title()) ; ?></a></h2>

        <img src= "<?php echo $imglink; ?>calendar.png"    class="recent_post_date_img"><div class="date_wrap"><p class="date1"><?php     the_date('m-d-Y', '', ''); ?></p></div>

   <div class="comment_wrap"> <?php comments_popup_link("$comm_link 0",   "$comm_link1", "% $comm_link"); ?></div>
   <div class="excerpt_class">
            <?php echo the_excerpt(25); ?>
  </div>        
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  wp_reset_query();

  ?>
</ul>


</div>
</div>

 <div class="sidebar1"><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );?></div>


   <div class="gap"></div>
    <?php $the_query2 = new WP_Query( 'cat=10', 'posts_per_page=1' );

    while ($the_query2 -> have_posts()) : $the_query2 -> the_post(); ?>            
        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
        <div class="wrap_video">  
         <div class="play_button"> </div>

    <?php 
   /*****     Thumbnail     ******/
  the_post_thumbnail(
      array(200, 200), 
      array(

      'class' => 'video_class_thumb',  //custom class for post thumbnail if   any 
        'alt' => 'post thumbnail', //post thumbnail alternate title
        'title' => 'my custom title' 
        )
    );?>
</div>
</a>

<?php   endwhile;     
wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the second query is due to the way that the parameters are passed. In the original code, two strings are being passed, which is not going to work:

```
 $the_query2 = new WP_Query( 'cat=10', 'posts_per_page=1' );
```

You can use an array (preferred method):

```
$the_query2 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'cat' => '10',
    'posts_per_page' => '1'
) );
```

Or use a query string:

```
 $the_query2 = new WP_Query( 'cat=10&posts_per_page=1' );
```

Comment: excellent clarity added here